# Nextpeer Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, nextpeer

I've integrated Nextpeer's push notification by following this guide:
https://developers.nextpeer.com/docs/view/iospushguide

However, i'm not sure how to enter my push notification's message as it was not stated in the document. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think that you should contact Nextpeer's official support mail (support [at] nextpeer [dot] com). Their support team is very responsive.

In anyway, Nextpeer automates the push notification system for you. You don't need to "send" any message. For example each time your user invites another user, Nextpeer sends a push notification automatically to the invitee.

Comment: If i want to send message to my users, how do i do it? For example, i want to send message to reward coins to my users for playing the game.

Comment: You cannot do that with Nextpeer push notification system. You will have to integrate another push solution. Check services like pushwoosh.

Comment: What's the use of push notification if can't send message?

Comment: That push notification system is not for your use. It is for the invite system. This how users can invite their friends into a match in Nextpeer.